# Best practice for caching Facebook friends in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise, koala

I have a Rails web app (Devise + Koala) where users log in using Facebook. Users interact with their Facebook friends inside the app.

Importing a users Facebook friends list for caching purposes is time consuming.

What are the best practices here:
Should I try to avoid friends caching altogether?
Should I do the import in a daemon background thread?

I'm aware of the Facebook real-time API for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the list in a cache is going to be less time-consuming than looking up the user's friend on facebook every time you want to retrieve them.

Postgres has a data type called hstore which lets you store data in a column as a hash rather than a serialized type. You can add to rails with this gem:
https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

It makes storing things like a cache of facebook friends easier; you can search through the hash with SQL statements.

So in your case you can tell facebook to subscribe to a change to the user's friends connection and point it to a callback in your app which updates the user's friendlist cache. Note you will need to replace the entire hash with the new list since atomic operations on a hstore aren't possible. Good luck!